# Reading XML file online

Tags: java, xml, parsing, file, uri

I was searching code that I can use to read XML file. and I did find one as below. But my problem is, I'm unable to read a XML file online. When I give the [URL of the XML file](http://www.cse.lk/listedcompanies/overview.htm?d-16544-e=3&6578706f7274=1) location, it returns File Not Found Exception. Can someone advice. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class XMLReader {

 public static void main(String argv[]) {

  try {
  File file = new File("MyXML.xml");
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = db.parse(file);
  doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
  System.out.println("Root element " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
  NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");
  System.out.println("Information of all employees");

  for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++) {

    Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(s);

    if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

           Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;
      NodeList fstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("firstname");
      Element fstNmElmnt = (Element) fstNmElmntLst.item(0);
      NodeList fstNm = fstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
      System.out.println("First Name : "  + ((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
      NodeList lstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("lastname");
      Element lstNmElmnt = (Element) lstNmElmntLst.item(0);
      NodeList lstNm = lstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
      System.out.println("Last Name : " + ((Node) lstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
    }

  }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read XML response from a URL in java,?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310139/how-to-read-xml-response-from-a-url-in-java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was discoused on stackoverflow: [How to read XML response from a URL in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310139/how-to-read-xml-response-from-a-url-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the java.net.URL class:

```
URL xmlURL = new URL("http://www.cse.lk/listedcompanies/overview.htm?d-16544-e=3&6578706f7274=1");
InputStream xml = xmlURL.openStream();
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(xml);
xml.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to communicate with a Restful Service, you might benefit from using a library. Open source libraries with goodies in this area include Apache CXF and Jersey.