# Use a Remote XML as File

Tags: java, android, xml, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read XML response from a URL in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310139/how-to-read-xml-response-from-a-url-in-java)

I'm trying to read an XML file from my web server and display the contents of it on a `ListView`, so I'm reading the file like this:

```
File xml = new File("http://example.com/feed.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xml);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList mainNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("article");
// for loop to populate the list...
```

The problem is that I'm getting this error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /http:/mydomainname.com/feed.xml (No such file or directory)

Why I'm having this problem and how to correct it?

Comment: File class does not download. plus you should use an [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.net.URI%29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File is meant to point to local files.

If you want to point to a remote URI, the easiest is to use the class url

```
 //modified code
 URL url = new URL("http://example.com/feed.xml");
 URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
 InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

 //your code
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
 Document doc = dBuilder.parse( in );
```

As you can see, later on, thanks to java streaming apis, you can easily adapt your code logic to work with the content of the file. This is due to an overload of the parse method in class `DocumentBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `HTTPURLConnection` to get xml as input stream and pass it `DocumentBuilder`, from there you can use the logic you have.

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(yourURL);

if(resp.getStatusCode == 200)
{
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(resp.getEntity().getContent());
}
```

Note: I just type here, there may be syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file using a URL object.  For instance, try something like this:

```
URL facultyURL = new URL("http://example.com/feed.xml");
InputStream is = facultyURL.openStream();
```

Comment: faculty ? You mean university ?

Comment: the code I posted is from an application for high schools that helps with end of the year exam scheduling.