# Exception reading xml on php page by http request on

Tags: php, android

I have a problem when I read an xml file from a php page and it includes the same data in another link.

The exception is detailed is [in this](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml) link.

The tutorial I am using is code [in this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/) link.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310139/how-to-read-xml-response-from-a-url-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the PHP file before your output is sent.

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/xml"); ?>
```

If the problem persists try checking your XML markup using this tool, [check xml markup](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_validate.asp).